# Create Azure Function App to clean Temp files of specific app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have several applications on Azure. What we need is to create Function App per Resource group that will, once a day, check specific folders for temporary files and clean them.

- first of all, is there a way to define such function app?
- do we need to create separate function app for each application per resource group? or we can create one function app that will handle all applications per resource group? how we should relate function app to specific web app?

is there a way to to this without creating function app?

Comment: What specific folders for temporary files would you like to clean? Is that Azure resources like web app? If it is, you could use a service named **Automation Account** to achieve.

Comment: In our web app we use telerik controls and some of them (usually file upload control) write in App_Data/RadUploadTemp, so that's one folder. On the other hand there is also API defined as app service which is the bigger problem because in their App_Data folder there are lot's of temp files that need to be cleaned once a day. So we are looking for a solution that will clean App_Data/RadUploadTemp for one app service and App_Data for other app service